# Ser rico / Estar rico

Tags: cópulas

como de costumbre los foros presentan 48 opiniones diferentes acerca de este asunto, así que vengo aquí con la esperanza de encontrar alguna respuesta más o menos categórica que ponga fin a eso de una vez por todas! Querría que me dijérais si las siguientes frases os parecen correctas o no:

1.

> La sopa es rica, no sé por qué a ti no te gusta.

En esta frase, se está hablando de la sopa *en general*, es decir, no de una sopa específica sino del plato "sopa" de por sí. La traducción al inglés sería:

> Soup is delicious, I don't know why you don't like it.

2. 

> La sopa está rica, tendrás que darme tu receta!

En esta frase, se está hablando de una sopa específica que están comiendo ahora mismo. La traducción al inglés sería:

> The/This/That soup is delicious, you'll have to give me your recipe!

Cuando empecé a aprender español, me explicaron que así funciona el adjetivo "rico"; que si se habla de un plato *en general*, se usa "ser", mientras que si se habla de un plato específico, se usa "estar".
Pero durante una discusión reciente con un amigo hispanohablante mío, me dijo lo contrario: que "rico" con el sentido de "que tiene buen sabor" siempre se usa con "estar", y que "ser rico" significa únicamente "que tiene mucho dinero".

Espero que podáis ayudarme a desenredarlo todo un poquito!

Comment: Has aprendido muy bien la diferencia entre "ser" y "estar". Tu amigo está equivocado. En lugar de "rica", podrías usar el adjetivo "sabrosa", y el resultado sería exactamente el mismo

Comment: Yo en cambio creo que tu amigo tiene razón. Si dices "la sopa es rica" mi respuesta sería "¿en qué?", porque pensaría que te refieres a algo como "la sopa es rica en vitaminas", por ejemplo. Si dices "la sopa está rica" entonces no hay duda, es que está buena. Igual es que esta pregunta puede depender del país del hablante, así que sugiero que especifiques en qué país aprendiste español, para obtener una respuesta más precisa. En mi caso, yo hablo español europeo.

Comment: Dos opiniones diferentes... a veces es demasiado difícil encontrar respuestas categóricas. ;_; Aprendí y sigo aprendiendo español europeo.

Comment: En ese caso, me abstendré de participar. Donde yo vivo, el buen sabor puede ser un rasgo permanente o temporario de un alimento o de una comida. Me gustaría saber cómo describen en España un alimento que se caracteriza por su buen sabor.

Comment: @Gustavson pues, aunque no sea completamente lógico, mi experiencia en España también es que "está rico"/"está bueno" se utilizan para describir el buen sabor tanto en sentido temporal como permanente: "el chocolate está muy rico". Con "sabroso", sí que se diferencia entre "es sabroso" y "está sabroso". Quizá es porque "rico" y "bueno" tienen otros significados con el verbo "ser": "La sopa es buena (para la salud)".

Comment: Vamos planificar la cena. Creo que la sopa de x sea rica [en un libro de cocina]. Pero la última vez que lo hice no estuvo rica. – La

Answer (score 2):

La RAE habla en el [párrafo 37.9m](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=besXqmEctHtEsCdU) de su *Gramática* acerca de los adjetivos que cambian su significado según si van con el verbo *ser* o con el verbo *estar*. Ejemplos:

- *ser listo* ('inteligente') ~ *estar listo* ('dispuesto', 'preparado');
- *ser malo* ('malvado') ~ *estar malo* ('desagradable', 'de mal sabor`);
- *ser sano* ('saludable') ~ *estar sano* ('con buena salud').

Como imaginarás, el adjetivo *[rico](https://dle.rae.es/rico)* no se salva de esta distinción:

- ***ser rico* ('adinerado') ~ *estar rico* ('sabroso').**

Así, cuando se habla de *ser rico* se habla siempre de tener mucho dinero. La excepción a esta norma es cuando se habla de que una cosa *es rica en* otra cosa, en la que el significado de "tener mucho dinero" cambia a "tener mucho de esa otra cosa":

> La naranja es rica en vitamina C.
> Las naranjas son ricas en vitamina C.

Se puede usar tanto el singular como el plural, tal y como se puede ver el anterior ejemplo, extraído del [párrafo 15.8g](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=beqzSqkBDVwIJODK) de la *Gramática*.

Por tanto, para hablar de comida usando el adjetivo *rico* se debe usar el verbo *estar*. Para hablar de que algo en general tiene buen sabor, es mejor usar el plural:

> Los plátanos están ricos.

Y para hablar de un objeto concreto, acompañar la frase de algún demostrativo:

> Este plátano está rico.

Lo que sí es que esta norma no suena muy bien con sustantivos incontables: *las sopas están ricas* me suena a que hay varias sopas en la mesa y todas están ricas. Me resulta complicado pensar en una frase que hable de las sopas en general en este caso.

Nótese que esto solo ocurre con el adjetivo *rico* dada su variedad de significados. Con otros adjetivos similares, como *sabroso*, esta distinción no se da y se pueden usar los verbos *ser* y *estar* como se usan comúnmente, para determinar si el adjetivo se usa de forma general o particular.

Comment: La sopa que se puede hacer asi es rica. Pero, cuando la hice, no salió bien.

Answer (score 1):

Con el adjetivo **rico**, al igual que con la mayoría de los demás adjetivos, el verbo "ser" se usa para indicar que la característica es normal, general o la estoy generalizando. Y el verbo "estar" se usa para decir que la característica es circunstancial.

Fíjate que para decir que algo ***es rico***, no es necesario que la característica se aplique a objetos *lógicamente* generales o "universales". Simplemente estamos diciendo que es una característica que ***ha acompañado casi siempre*** al objeto (ingrediente, receta, plato) del que estamos hablando.

Y por su parte, cuando decimos que algo ***está rico*** indicamos que la característica ***la hemos detectado ahora***, independiente de cómo sea lo normal. Puede que generalmente su sabor sea bueno o malo, pero *ahora* está bueno.

Algunos ejemplos:

> Tus pasteles de chocolate **son ricos**, pero éstos están sencillamente sublimes.
>
> Tus pasteles de chocolate son un poco desabridos, pero los que cocinaste hoy **están ricos**.
>
> Tus pasteles de chocolate son sublimes, pero éstos solo **están ricos**.

Comment: Exactamente. Muy sencilla respuesta.